# Bash string concat does not work - Result of concat is empty

Tags: string, bash, concatenation

I try to build a Git prepare-commit-msg hook, that provides the following output for the git bash (mingw32):

```
<file1>:
 -
<file2>:
 - 
...
```

And

```
#!/bin/bash
git diff --cached --name-status | while read line; do echo $OUTPUT$line$':\n - \n'; done
```

works great

`git diff --cached --name-status` prints `<mode>\t<filePath>` for each file in the index that has changed.

But when I do

```
#!/bin/bash
git diff --cached --name-status | while read line; do OUTPUT=$OUTPUT$line$':\n - \n'; done
echo $OUTPUT
```

or

```
#!/bin/bash
git diff --cached --name-status | while read line; do OUTPUT+=$line$':\n - \n'; done
echo $OUTPUT
```

`$OUTPUT` is empty

This also works fine

```
COUNTER=0
         while [  $COUNTER -lt 10 ]; do
             TEST+=$COUNTER$':\n'
             let COUNTER=COUNTER+1 
         done
echo $TEST
```

What am I doing wrong?

**SOLVED**

```
#!/bin/bash
git diff --cached --name-status | { 
while read line; do
    output=$output$var$':\n  - \n'
done
echo "$output" > $1
}
```

Comment: What is the output of `git diff --cached --name-status`? It would be helpful if you [edit]ed your question to show us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're using a pipe, the `while` loop is run in a subshell, so when that subshell exits, its variables disappear with it. You're left with the `$OUTPUT` variable from the *parent* shell which is empty.

You have to ensure you build up OUTPUT in the parent shell:

```
while read line; do
    OUTPUT+=$line$':\n - \n'
done < <(git diff --name-status)
echo "$OUTPUT"
```

or use the "lastpipe" setting to run the last command of a pipeline in the current shell (job control needs to be off)

```
set +m; shopt -s lastpipe
git diff --name-status | while read line; do OUTPUT+=$line$':\n - \n'; done
echo "$OUTPUT"
```

Or, output the variable in the subshell

```
git diff --name-status | { 
    while read line; do OUTPUT+="$line"$':\n - \n'; done
    echo "$OUTPUT"
}
```

Other notes:

- You need to quote `"$OUTPUT"` if you want to preserve all those newlines.
- Get out of the habit of using UPPERCASEVARIABLES: leave those reserved for the shell.

Comment: The first two solutions do not work in the mingw32 bash. The third works fine.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to build up a variable `OUTPUT` at all. Just write the output as you read the input. (Using `printf` is a little cleaner and more standard than using `echo`.)

```
git diff --cached --name-status | while read line; do
    printf '%s:\n - \n' "$line"
done
```

Comment: I used the variable output, because I need to write the output to the file given in $1. So after the loop finally worked, I redirect the echo to $1.

Comment: You can redirect the output of the loop to the file. `while ...; do ...; done > "$1"`.

Comment: @BlackEye, better solution than mine